# Cross-validation for best subset selection

Tags: cross-validation, subset

Rephrasing my question:
I have predictors $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,X_2,X_3,...)$ and want to find the best subset for predicting some variable *Y*. My interest lies not in linear prediction, but using nearest neighbors.

Here are two alternative algorithms and I wonder which one contains a correct application of cross validation:

**First approach:**

1. Rank the $X_i$ in $\mathbf{X}$ by their association with $Y$
2. Use cross-validation to find the best *number* $\widehat{p}$ of predictors from the ranked set $\mathbf{X}$. To this end I predict $Y$ with $p=1,2,3$ of the ranked predictors using nearest-neighbor prediction and RMSE as a skill metric. The $p$ with minimal error across all folds is the best $\widehat{p}$

All of this I do on the learning set (which I subdivide for the cross-validation into 5 folds). This gives quite good prediction results on an independent test set of the data. However, in Section 7.10.2 "The Wrong and Right Way to Do Cross-validation" in the Elements of Statistical Learning it says:

> In general, with a multistep modeling procedure, cross-validation must
>   be applied to the entire sequence of modeling steps. In particular, samples
>   must be “left out” before any selection or filtering steps are applied.

...and it seems I should not do any ranking involving the target variable $Y$ before hand. So I tested an alternative

**Second approach:**

1. Subdivide learning set into 5 folds and in each fold

   1. Rank the $X_i$ in $\mathbf{X}$ by their association with $Y$
   2. Predict $Y$ for different numbers $p=1,2,3$ of the ranked predictors
2. Choose $\widehat{p}$ which gave minimal average error across all folds

While this seems to be a correct way to use cross validation, the prediction results are mostly worse compared to the first approach. I think the reason is that the ranking leads to different predictors in each fold introducing too much variance for determining $\widehat{p}$...

What do you think, is the first approach valid? Note that I am *not* interested in evaluating the generalization performance...

Last question: In a variation, I added a pre-selection to the first approach:

Zeroth step: Pre-select a subset $\mathbf{S}$ from $\mathbf{X}$ by exploiting the associations of each $X_i$ with $Y$ and then do the ranking only on $\mathbf{S}$

...which eliminates some predictors before I do the ranking. This gave even better results, albeit it seems to go against the rule not to do any pre-selection involving the target variable outside of cross-validation...
Any ideas?

Comment: Don't have time for answer right now, but cross validation (and/or bootstrapping) has two main applications: 1. tuning model parameters (size of feature set, penalization parameters, etc.) and 2. estimating the generalization performence of the model. Note that one cross validation can only do one of these at a time, otherwise you need nested cross validation. (you are optimizing 2 when doing 1). Feature selection is not a meaningful application.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can paste in whatever context from the book is necessary to answer your question.

Comment: @Erik and gung: I rephrased my question, hope its clearer now!